# .SV4 video file won't play in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, dvr

I have a program called JDVR that is recording feeds from analog security cameras (BNC connectors). The directory where the DVR files are stored has several .SV4 files of various sizes (from 12 KB to 923 MB), but I cannot play any of them.

I thought VLC should play them, but even the longest one (largest file) just stalls and won't play. We had a possible break-in over the weekend, so I really need these to play. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The supplier of JDVR should supply a player, or at least a codec. They should be your first port of call.

Comment: Thank you, I agree but I cannot find a single bit of contact info for them. I bought the analog capture cards at Micro Center, but they are no help.

Comment: In general, what program plays .SV4 video files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SV4's are basically only used in CCTV/security systems, and they (the security system manufacturer) usually provide a player. Unless you have a compatible CODEC for that format, you're not going to be able to play them with 'standard' video players.

There *are* converters out there to convert SV4 files into standard formats, like AVI.

Here's one: [The Surveillance Video Converter](http://www.cctvtools.net/en/index.htm)

[image]

*Note: I have no association with this software, nor have I used it.

Comment: Works perfectly, just what I needed! Thanks again!